# How do I reuse a UIViewRepresentable UIKit component?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, swiftui, swiftui-form

Due to the limitations of SwiftUI, I usually need to jump back into to UIKit and take advantage of UIKit components. This is all good, but I'm finding that I usually need to keep creating separate structs to hold the functionality I need.

For example. Let's say I have a form with 4 fields, e.g. first name, last name, email, and password. I usually need to create separate UIViewRepresentable UIKit components for each.

I'm currently working on a project where I have 2 simple sliders that update 2 different labels when they are moved. Reusing the same UIViewRepresentable UISlider component in SwiftUI treats both sliders as 1, because they both reference the same view model property, hence me needing to create separate components rather than reusing them.

I figured I might as well just see if there is a more efficient way to do this as I've been duplicating code for quite some time now, and there usually isn't much difference in the code apart from things like what kind of keypad to show, colours etc.

Below, is an example of how I tap into UIKit from SwiftUI. I'm creating a screen that will allow bet odds and a stake to be selected using sliders.

I track when the slider's value is changed and store the value in a @Published var from my view model.

```
self.bViewModel.odds
```

I access this view model through an environment variable in the view where the slider is used, and use it to update a Text label.

```
VStack {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("\(self.bViewModel.odds)")
             .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
             .foregroundColor(Color("CustomPurple"))
            .frame(minHeight: 0)
            .padding(.top, 3)
            .padding(.bottom, 3)

         Spacer()
    }

    SliderView()
        .frame(minHeight: 25, maxHeight: 25)

}
.padding(.bottom, 30)
```

The SliderView struct looks like this:

```
struct SliderView: UIViewRepresentable {

    final class Coordinator: NSObject {

        @EnvironmentObject var bViewModel: BViewModel

        init(bViewModel: EnvironmentObject<BViewModel>)
        {
            self._bViewModel = bViewModel
        }

        // Create a valueChanged(_:) action
        @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

            self.bViewModel.odds = Double(sender.value)
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SliderView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(bViewModel: self._bViewModel)
    }

    @EnvironmentObject var bViewModel: BViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
        let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
        slider.minimumValue = 0.00
        slider.maximumValue = 100.00

        slider.addTarget(
             context.coordinator,
             action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)),
             for: .valueChanged
           )

        return slider
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISlider, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

Now, I need a slider for the stake selection, but I can't reuse the same slider from above without writing a bunch of code to make it treat it as a different slider. It's just easier to duplicate the code and change the line where I access my view model's odds variable so that it access the stakes variable instead, e.g.

```
    @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        self.bViewModel.stake = Double(sender.value)
    }
```

This is how I've been working for months, but it has always felt wrong. However, I can't seem to think of another way to approach this.

Any suggestions? How do you usually handle this kind of situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " Reusing the same UIViewRepresentable UISlider component in SwiftUI treats both sliders as 1," really? please show us your code where this happens, so we can help

Comment: There should not be a problem to use a component as many as you want. It is the power of it. I think the problem is somewhere else, it is better If you share the exact code.

Comment: I think the problem is that you set one binding variable to both sliders and in this way, it's effects on both of them, you should pass separate `@State` var for each slider

Comment: @Chris I've updated my question

Comment: @FRIDDAY It gets complicated when using a view model.

Comment: @Mac3n This is the problem. I explained a little further in my updated question. The easy way to over come this is to just create another slider. It just feels wrong not being able to reuse that code, especially when I only need to update 1 line.

Comment: you bind your slider representable to your viewmodel? i think this is not good and should not be done. you should give the slider representable a binding property which then changes its value and the caller can do whatever it wants with it.

Comment: @Chris I could do that, but then I'm unable to use my view model. For example,  If I declare a state var, then my slider representable struct can access it using binding, but how will I then be able to get the slider value to my view model?

Comment: you would need one variable for each slider in your view model

Comment: @Chris , I understand that part totally. But what I mean is, how can my view access the individual variables from the view model? I declare an environment variable along with all my state variables like this: EnvironmentObject var bViewModel: BViewModel . I'm unable to access the object's properties. I'm also unable to set the object's properties in the view body. This is why I decided to do it in the slider uirepresentable struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new Answer, now with EnvironmentObject

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {

    @Published var sliderValue1 : Double = 3.14
    @Published var sliderValue2 : Double = 42.0
    @Published var sliderValue3 : Double = 3.14
    @Published var sliderValue4 : Double = 42.0
}

struct SliderView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var value : Double

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var sliderView: SliderView

        init(_ sliderView: SliderView) {
            self.sliderView = sliderView
        }

        @objc func valueChanged(_ slider: UISlider) {
            sliderView.value = Double(slider.value)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
        let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
        slider.minimumValue = 0.00
        slider.maximumValue = 100.00

        slider.addTarget(
             context.coordinator,
             action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)),
             for: .valueChanged
           )

        return slider
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISlider, context: Context) {

    }
}

struct ContentView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.viewModel.sliderValue1)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.viewModel.sliderValue1 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.viewModel.sliderValue1 = $0
            }))

            Text("\(self.viewModel.sliderValue2)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.viewModel.sliderValue2 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.viewModel.sliderValue2 = $0
            }))


            Text("\(viewModel.sliderValue3)")
            SliderView(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.viewModel.sliderValue3 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.viewModel.sliderValue3 = $0
            }))
            Text("\(viewModel.sliderValue4)")
            SliderView(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.viewModel.sliderValue4 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.viewModel.sliderValue4 = $0
            }))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        var value1 : Double = 0.4
        var value2 : Double = 0.4
        var value3 : Double = 0.4
        var value4 : Double = 0.4

        return ContentView().environmentObject(ViewModel())
    }
}
```

---

ok, because you are so polite and really answer quickly i tried it and hopefully now i got, what you needed ;)

i did let the "old sliders" in it, but now the lower two sliders are from my UIViewRepresentable.

NEW ANSWER:

```
struct SliderView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var value : Double

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var sliderView: SliderView

        init(_ sliderView: SliderView) {
            self.sliderView = sliderView
        }

        @objc func valueChanged(_ slider: UISlider) {
            sliderView.value = Double(slider.value)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
        let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
        slider.minimumValue = 0.00
        slider.maximumValue = 100.00

        slider.addTarget(
             context.coordinator,
             action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)),
             for: .valueChanged
           )

        return slider
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISlider, context: Context) {

    }
}

struct ContentView : View {

    @State var sliderValue1 : Double
    @State var sliderValue2 : Double

    @State var sliderValue3 : Double
    @State var sliderValue4 : Double

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(sliderValue1)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.sliderValue1 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.sliderValue1 = $0
            }))

            Text("\(sliderValue2)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.sliderValue2 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.sliderValue2 = $0
            }))


            Text("\(sliderValue3)")
            SliderView(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.sliderValue3 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.sliderValue3 = $0
            }))
            Text("\(sliderValue4)")
            SliderView(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.sliderValue4 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.sliderValue4 = $0
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

OLD ANSWER:

ok, i figured it out how you can do it without UIViewRepresentable.

See this example.

All you have to do is extend your viewModel with your sliderVariables (sliderValue1 or whatever name you like) and

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var sliderValue1 : Double
    @State var sliderValue2 : Double

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(sliderValue1)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.sliderValue1 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.sliderValue1 = $0
            }))

            Text("\(sliderValue2)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.sliderValue2 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.sliderValue2 = $0
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the new answer. Could you possibly explain where you are referencing the view model in ContentView? I noticed there isn't an environment var.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you recommend a site where I can read about the behaviour you implemented in the content view? Specifically the value you passed into the Slider. I've never seen this done before. I didn't realise a view model could have it's properties written to this way.

Comment: Found it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding

Comment: It's working fine for odds. Is there a way to make it so the sliderview isn't limited to doubles?

Comment: you can use any value you want...just convert it

Comment: I figured it out in the end. I made the binding variable type Any, then I used typing casting and down casting. I have a lot of earlier code to update now, but your example is a much cleaner than how I was originally doing things and will save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i figured it out how you can do it without UIViewRepresentable.

See this example.

All you have to do is extend your viewModel with your sliderVariables (sliderValue1 or whatever name you like) and use these values instead of my State-variables.

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var sliderValue1 : Double
    @State var sliderValue2 : Double

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(sliderValue1)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.sliderValue1 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.sliderValue1 = $0
            }))

            Text("\(sliderValue2)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(get:
                { return self.sliderValue2 },
                                          set: {
                                            print($0)
                                            self.sliderValue2 = $0
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I am stuck with UIRepresentable because the slider needed some customisation that was impossible using SwiftUI's slider.

Comment: yes, but i did not know this, because you wrote "
I'm currently working on a project where I have 2 ***simple*** sliders", so i thought it would be enough ;)